# Is Necromancer badge broken?

Tags: bug, badges, necromancer-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the question which awarded me “Necromancer” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47127/how-to-get-the-question-which-awarded-me-necromancer-badge)
>   [Got the Necromancer badge, but for what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48812/got-the-necromancer-badge-but-for-what)

I can't tell what answer I was awarded it for; I haven't answered many, and none of them looks 60 days old.

Comment: No, your reputation on meta will not affect your SO reputation. They are independant of each other.

Comment: Awarding the badge after the fact seems weird. I posted [an answer](http://superuser.com/questions/58878/how-to-list-encrypted-files-in-windows-7/697626#697626) more than a year ago and got the badge today. Doesn't seem logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818159/what-are-some-bad-programming-habits-to-look-out-for-and-avoid/1771303#1771303

It is for that question.  It was asked on May 3rd and you answered on Nov 20th. It obviously got more than 5 up votes.

Comment: I beat you by 53 seconds - neener neener!

Comment: I see. My answers get ordered by *reply* date, not by *question* date. Thanks. I hope negative reputation on meta doesn't spill out to SO ... :-)

Comment: Technically, Adam did beat me. Haha.  He deserves the accepted answer more than I because we said pretty much the same thing.  I can't delete this answer though cause it is the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818159/what-are-some-bad-programming-habits-to-look-out-for-and-avoid/1771303#1771303

It was asked in may, you answered in Novemeber and got over 5 upvotes.

Comment: Well, I guess the extra upvotes will have to suffice until OP re-selects your answer. ;)

Comment: hehe, no problem, really!  As long as the question is answered - that's all that matters.