# How to get the question which awarded me "Necromancer" badge?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, necromancer-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

I am out of town for two days and this morning i saw i have been awarded "Necromancer" badge... How to get the question which awarded me "Necromancer" badge?

Comment: You didn't happen to raise any dead while you were out of town?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149227/167443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741581/what-are-the-worst-working-conditions-you-have-written-code-in/2644584#2644584

**Asked:** Apr 12 '09 at 10:35
**Answered:** Apr 15 ('10) at 10:53

That would be more than 60 days later. You also have 11 up votes on it.

Comment: @capcha but it was a new question the moderators have merged it with an original question... The new question was marked as duplicate of the previous question...

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have at least five upvotes for in the past two days, has to be a recently submitted answer to an old question though.