# Got the Necromancer badge, but for what?

Tags: support, necromancer-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the question which awarded me “Necromancer” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47127/how-to-get-the-question-which-awarded-me-necromancer-badge)

I've just got my second Necromancer badge on SO and for the life of me I can't figure out what answer it's for. I don't have any recent answers to old questions as far as I can see.

Comment: Not a duplicate. While that question is a feature request this is a support request that will possibly turn into a bug if nobody can provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That's probably the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157361/whats-a-good-non-programming-interview-question-when-hiring-a-programmer/410266#410266), answered more than 60 days later, and with 5 upvotes.

Since it's a CW, this is probably why you haven't noticed the recent upvote on it.

For information, you have only two answers which are matching the condition, and the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175545/worst-technobabble-youve-ever-heard/1142980#1142980) has 15 votes, leading me to think this is the one which gave you the previous necromancer badge.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the one. I forgot about CW.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you gave the answer earlier, and recently got the fifth vote. Necromancer answer requires atleast 5 votes.

Maybe one of these. I didn't check carefully, at least answer date was far from question date in these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157361/whats-a-good-non-programming-interview-question-when-hiring-a-programmer/410266#410266
- [Worst technobabble you've ever heard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175545/worst-technobabble-youve-ever-heard/1142980#1142980)

You get badges also from Community Wiki posts.

Comment: I can't see any such recent votes, either. I only have a handful of answers with 5 votes or more and I can't find any among them that were to an old question.

Answer (score 1):

I often find them quickly by sorting the answers on *Views* and then checking the post date of all 5+ voted answers. Older topics have generally more views, you know.

I just checked your answers and indeed, the second and third 5+ answers when sorted on *Views* are both eligible for `Necromancer` badge.

It also occurred once to me that a fresh new topic was merged with an older topic, which caused that my 5+ voted answer is technically 60+ days older than the merged question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a necromancer badge after answering a recent question, getting 5 upvotes, then  that was later merged into an old question as an exact duplicate, so my upvoted answer was moved to the old question. I'm not sure, but I can't figure out what else could have happened. Is this a bug?

My answer is:
[How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script/3016198#3016198)

Comment: Now that you asked a [proper question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53302/necromancer-badge-anomaly) about it, please delete this post which is not an answer.